# Sharing a Legend between two combined ggplots

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

I'm currently trying to present two time series using ggplot2, both with very different scales, using two ggplots. I've combined the two separate ggplots, one on top of the other, using `grid.arrange`. In order to aid visualization, I'd like to make each line a different colour, and have this legend below the combined plot.

As this may be relevant, I'm currently working in the confines of creating a shiny section of an R markdown document. Hence the renderPlot wrapper around `grid.arrange`.

The following is similar to the code that I currently have.

```
testdata = data.frame(var1 = seq(0,10,by=1), var2 = runif(11), 
var3 = runif(11, min = 100, max = 500))

renderPlot({grid.arrange(
ggplot(data = testdata, aes(x = var1, y = var2))
+ geom_line(colour = "blue") + xlab(NULL),
ggplot(data = testdata, aes(x = var1, y = var3)) + geom_line(colour = "red"))})
```

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to create the shared legend? Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Since this an R-specific question, it's technically off-topic and will probably be put on hold. Hadley Wickham (who made ggplot) has a Google group mailing list thing, though. You can post the question there and get some suggestions.

Comment: See Hadley's wiki post [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Share-a-legend-between-two-ggplot2-graphs)  "create four plots p1, p2, p3 and p4. Save the legend of p1 as a separate grob. Strip the legends from the plots. Draw the four plots and the legend below them." WIth recent versions of ggplot, you need to add library(grid) to the code given in the wiki.

Answer (score 3):

using `ggplot2` I usually use the following 2 methods to create a common legend:

**Method 1 : When scales are similar**

By using `facet_grid` or just the `color` parameter in combination with `reshape2` package, you can easily combine multiple plots with same legend. But this is ideal in case the values in your variables have a similar magnitude order.

*Using `color` & `reshape2`:*

```
library('reshape2')
data_melt<-melt(data=testdata,value.name='Value',id.vars='var1')

ggplot(data_melt)+
  geom_line(aes(x=var1,y=Value,color=variable))
```

[image: High difference in magnitude leads to a poor plot, but similar scales might result in a good plot]

*Using `color`, `facet_grid` & `reshape2`:*

```
library('reshape2')
data_melt<-melt(data=testdata,value.name='Value',id.vars='var1')

ggplot(data_melt)+
 geom_line(aes(x=var1,y=Value,color=variable))+
 facet_grid(~variable)
```

[image: High difference in magnitude leads to a poor plot, but similar scales might result in a good plot]

**Method 2: When scales differ wildly**

[image: Value vs ID plot : combined]

As you can see,the final plot is great!
All you need is to create a plot having your legend & pass it as an input parameter to the custom function created in the [wiki here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Share-a-legend-between-two-ggplot2-graphs).

```
testdata = data.frame(var1 = seq(0,10,by=1), var2 = runif(11), 
                  var3 = runif(11, min = 100, max = 500))

library('reshape2')
data_melt<-melt(data=testdata,value.name='Value',id.vars='var1')

p1=ggplot(data = testdata)+
  geom_line(aes(x = var1, y = var2,color='blue'))

p2=ggplot(data = testdata) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = var1, y = var3,color='red'))

p3=ggplot(data_melt)+
   geom_line(aes(x=var1,y=Value,color=variable))

grid.arrange(p1,p2,nrow=2,main='Line Plots')

g_legend<-function(a.gplot){
tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
return(legend)}

legend <- g_legend(p3)
lwidth <- sum(legend$width)

## using grid.arrange for convenience
## could also manually push viewports
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p1 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                         p2 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                         main ="Variable Name",
                         left = "Value"),
             legend, 
             widths=unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - lwidth, lwidth), nrow=1)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm implementing your code, but when I run the markdown document, I get the error `Error: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)` Do you have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you using shiny?
The error you are getting seems to be thrown out by shiny.
You might want to take a look at this discussion:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/5i1qUC8EyYE